# Trying to assign text to variable and use in css class in PHP

Tags: php

I have the following code:

```
<?php //Loop through array and display results in table
while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($results)){
$date = $row['nc_date'];
$rowstatus = $row['nc_status'];

if ($rowstatus == 'open') {
$cssName = 'openstatus';
}else {
$cssName = 'responded';
}
?>

<tr class='<?php echo $cssName ?>'>
<td><?php echo $rowstatus?></td>
<td><?php echo $cssName?></td>
```

Here is an image of the table:

[image]

Notice that no matter what the row status is it assigns the cssname "responded".

Here is the information from the view source on the two rows:

```
<tr class='responded'>
<td>Responded</td>
<td>responded</td>

<tr class='responded'>
<td>Open</td>
<td>responded</td>
```

Comment: Have you tried dumping the value of `$rowstatus` to see what it equals?

Comment: its because you are comparing to 'open' when it's actually 'Open' with the capital O

Comment: It's case sensitive. Try `if ($rowstatus == 'Open') {`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your result I can see this :

```
<tr class='responded'>
<td>Open</td>
<td>responded</td>
```

So the `$rowstatus` value is not `open` but `Open`. So change :

```
if ($rowstatus == 'open') {
```

by :

```
if ($rowstatus == 'Open') {
```

Comment: Case sensitivity is going to be the death of me. Thanks for the quick answer.